# Always display the left of the join and display the right only if any and if it matches a clause

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables, a `client` table, a `user` table and a `user_has_client` table.

The `user_has_client` table is there to join the 2 others, but it also has a `roles` column.

```
MariaDB [extrapack]> desc user;
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id        | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email          | varchar(255)         | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |

MariaDB [extrapack]> desc client;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| client_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

MariaDB [extrapack]> desc user_has_client;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| client_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| roles     | tinytext         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

There may be multiple different `roles` for a `client` and a `user`, and the `roles` column is an array.

```
MariaDB [extrapack]> select * from user_has_client where roles != "" limit 3;
+---------+-----------+---------+
| user_id | client_id | roles   |
+---------+-----------+---------+
|     181 |       395 | cpa, ce |
|     181 |       473 | cpa     |
|     181 |       498 | cpa     |
+---------+-----------+---------+
```

But one client can offer only one same role to one user. For example, there cannot be two different users having the `cpa` role on one same client.

I would like to list one client, and for the client, list only the one user that has the role `cpa` if there is such a user.

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT c.client_id AS client_id0, ou.user_id AS user_id3, ou.email AS email5 FROM client c LEFT JOIN user_has_client ouhc ON c.client_id = ouhc.client_id LEFT JOIN user ou ON ouhc.user_id = ou.user_id AND ouhc.roles LIKE '%cpa%' WHERE c.client_id = 265 ORDER BY ou.email DESC;
```

There may or may not be a joining record for a `client` and a `user`, but even so, I still want to display a list line for the `client`, so I cannot do an inner join and have to do a left join.

But doing a left join, I still want only one list line per client.

As of now, the above statement gives me `n` lines for the client, for `n` users have a join on this client. But only one of these `n` users has a `cpa` role in its join. So I want to display only one list line, and with that user.

So, to sum it up, I always want one line per client, and only one line, and with its user of the given role, say the `cpa` role, if any for that client.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the question if the unique index is on the user id - role fields, or the client id - role combination. `But one client can offer only one same role to one user. For example, there cannot be one same user having the cpa role on two different clients.` The quoted sentences are unclear, the example does not apply to the 1st sentence of the quote.

Comment: The second sentence of the quote is indeed wrong. My mistake. I shall correct it in the question. It should read `For example, there cannot be two different users having the cpa role on one same client.`

Comment: I rephrased the question title for better focus on the actual issue.

Comment: If the left join is the main issue here, then this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Shadow As can be seen in the MySQL statement of the question, I had already applied the same solution displayed in the existing duplicate question, that is, having the clause with a `AND` following the `ON` of the join: `LEFT JOIN user ou ON ouhc.user_id = ou.user_id AND ouhc.roles LIKE '%cpa%' `. But it still displays many rows when I need it to display only one. On a side note, I reckon the existing duplicate question is misleading as the `WHERE` clause sitting in the `ON` clause is applied, not `before`, but only on those records that are a match for the join, and not to the other records.

Comment: I created a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2aab7a/1/0 with some comments in it.

Comment: Nope, you have not applied the solution described in the duplicate topic. The duplicate topic describes filtering on the **right** hand side table, but in your code you filter on the **left** hand side table.

Comment: @Shadow The filtering is not `WHERE c.client_id` but it is `AND ouhc.roles LIKE '%cpa%'` and isn't that applied on the right hand side ? If not, would you care to show on the fiddle, how to apply it the way you have in mind ?

Comment: I want to avoid the 1+n pattern but could settle for a 1+1 pattern. So I think I could first fetch all the clients, and then fetch only the ones having a user with the given role. I think I could achieve this using an inner join, and merge the two result sets.

Comment: check again in which `on` clause is the `AND ouhc.roles LIKE '%cpa%'` condition pls. And check in the **corresponding** join on which side the `ouhc` table is...

Comment: Sorry but I'm unable to follow you. The `user_has_client` table is a join table and thus each and every one of its record has a matching `user` and a matching `client`. The `client` table is on the left. The `user` table is on the right. If the glitch is so easy to see then feel free to update the fiddle, and I might see better. As a side note, I solved my issue by doing a 1+1 pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably change your plan up a little bit. Make `user_has_client.roles` only carry one role per row. Then, if you want to only allow one of a role for each client, set a UNIQUE constraint on `user_id` and `role`.

Comment: I cannot have only one role instead of an array of roles. The uniqueness of these roles has no side effect on my issue. Even if only one role was contained in the roles column the issue would still be there. I would use an `=` instead of a `like` but that would not change the select statement issue I have. I think.

Comment: @Stephane Daniel did not suggest you to have a single role per user. He suggested - quite rightly - that each user - client - role arrangement should be stored in its own record. This way you can enforce the uniqueness you described via a unique key.

Comment: Carrying only one role per row would produce even more join records. It could be cleaner as in being more explicit. But I'm on a legacy schema and cannot touch too much of it. Having the roles all in one column avoids disrupting the existing code. Anyway, my question is not about enforcing uniqueness at all. If you take away the multi role aspect, and only consider one possible role of 'cpa', my issue remains.